# MYSQL - Insert of two values with where condition of another table not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying two insert two values (one is a select from another table with a condition) into a table ... but the below returns me an error:

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO animate_2 (number_records, type) 
     VALUES ((SELECT secty_cd, COUNT(*) 
              FROM securities 
              WHERE secty_cd = 'EQS'
             ), 'eqs'
            );
```

> ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

The subquery works though:

```
mysql> SELECT secty_cd, COUNT(*) FROM securities WHERE secty_cd = 'EQS';
+----------+----------+
| secty_cd | COUNT(*) |
+----------+----------+
| EQS      |    37316 |
+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need values here, you can simply write your query like following.

```
INSERT INTO animate_2 (number_records,type) 
SELECT Count(*) , 'eqs'
FROM   securities 
WHERE  secty_cd = 'EQS'
```

Comment: This is much the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change this 
`INSERT INTO animate_2 (number_records, type) VALUES ((SELECT secty_cd, COUNT(*) FROM securities WHERE secty_cd = 'EQS'), 'eqs');`

To

`INSERT INTO animate_2 (number_records, type) VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM securities WHERE secty_cd = 'EQS'), 'eqs');`